# Android Image to Base64

Tags: java, android, image, encoding, zip

I want to convert my app images to base64 so it won't show on the gallery. I have tried various techniques. The image is from a zip file so it is a byte array at that point. The length of the base64 change when I change the byte array size. What is the proper byte array size? And the base64 encoded image doesn't work too.
The primary code is
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.DEFAULT);
buffer is the byte array(102400)
and it contains the image too.
The image is a 7KB file and the output is 400KB

Comment: You can use the Base64 Android class:

String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);

Comment: I included your answer in my question. And it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Wtong solution.  If you want to prevent images from appearing in gallery, create a .nomedia file in that directory and the indexer will skip it

Comment: It doesn't sound like the image fills the entire buffer...

Comment: Kindly answer your solution Gabe

Answer (score 2):

You may try following function to convert image into `Base64`:

```
public void toStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Above function takes `Bitmap` image and converts it into `Base64 encoded string`. This is working in my project and I hope this will help you too.